# ng-repeat value is not visible inside nested tag

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and trying to work with `ng-repeat` but somehow ng-repeat's key/value is not visible if I am trying to print it in nested tags

**working:**

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="prop in array">
            <td><span ng-bind-html="prop.field1"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**And below code is not working:-**

```
<div ng-repeat="prop in array">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><span ng-bind-html="prop.field1"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Updated:**

```
var $app = angular.module('apps', ['ngSanitize']);
$app.controller('cntr', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.guestList = [{
        dob: '12/12/12'
    }];
}]);
```

Comment: `is not working` is not a proper problem statement

Comment: Could you provide the gustList?

Because in the second case it is not possible to determine the error

Comment: @K.K please see here http://jsfiddle.net/4q8fyq9v/ seems to be fine

Comment: @sylwester: yes it's working in jsfiddle shared by you, I guess there are some other problem, thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

For html to show properly in angular js you have to 'sanitize' it, using the $sce provider from AngularJS. Read here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

In principle, before you bind your variable to html output, you have to sanitize it like this:

```
$scope.guest.sanitizedInput = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.guest.res_addr1);
```

and html:

```
<td class="table-column-value res-addr1-value"><span ng-bind-html="guest.sanitizedInput"></span>
```